# If an object exist, take an action in python

Tags: python, object, if-statement, action

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to make an if then statement as the one used in Delphi. I looked at other posts about this but all the examples I've encountered are with "print". I have an object that I want to handle if appears, for example if object(name_mapping) exists then take action x and action y. Can somebody help me?

if (object_mapping) is not none:

Comment: Why would it be any different with print from any other action?

Comment: The examples I encountered were with print "message" and I wanted my script to take action, maybe print can do that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can approach this, this first and recommended one is using a dictionary. Have a dictionary that you use for your dynamically defined objects

```
object_mapping = {}
object_mapping['my_object'] = 42

    if 'my_object' in object_mapping:
        # do this if the object is defined
        pass
    else:
        #do this if the object is NOT defined
        pass
```

The other way of doing this, and its not wise to use this, is using try catch blocks

```
try:
    do_stuff(object_mapping) # will only run if object_mapping is defined
except NameError:
    #will only run if object_mapping is NOT defined
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(object_mapping is not None):
    #Your code if the object exists
else:
    #Your code if it doesn't
```

Comment: Thank you so much, all i had to do was put the "is not none" in the brackets. So close, yet so far :)))

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this,

```
if object_mapping:
   # code
else:
   # code
```